# apt-offline Parsing Error E: Lzma_read Read Error (7) package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, ubuntu-18.04, apt

### Context

I have a old laptop running on `Kubuntu 18.04` that I didn't use for a while and want to update using `apt-offline`. The Laptop cannot be connected to internet.

`apt-offline` is already installed on the laptop, and functional.

Using the classical process:

```sh
# On laptop
apt-offline set update.sig

# On Internet PC
apt-offline get --bundle updates.zip update.sig

# On laptop
apt-offline install updates.zip
```

### Problem

Until here everything seems fine. **But !** If I try any apt command after this, I have a `Read Error`:

```sh
# On Offline Laptop
sudo apt-offline set --upgrade upgrade.zip
# Gathering details for the 'upgrade' operation
# E: Lzma_read Read Error (7) 
# E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
# ERROR: FATAL: Something is wrong with the APT system
```

Almost all APT commands give the same result. (the two `E:` lines)

I tried to not `--bundle` in a zip but save packages in a directory, but same problems.

### Source of the Problem

After some digging, it seems that files are correctly formatted, but my guts told me to check the change-log of apt-offline. And... what I didn't find... See below:

```markdown
> 1.8.2-1
> Superseded in sid-release on 2020-04-30
# (...) skip to line 30
  * Switch to 3.0 (quilt) source format
  * Update debian/gbp.conf about switch to 3.0 (quilt) source format
```

So my guess, is that they changed the format of the apt sources files. Unfortunately, I didn't see any backward compatibility in the man.

### Foreseen Solutions

I see a few options here :

1. Use a converter to convert the new file format to the old one
2. Manually install a new version of apt on the offline laptop so its supports the new syntax
3. Find a way to tell `apt-offline` to save as old file format
4. Install a old version of `apt-offline` on my internet PC

### Questions

I would like to know what you think about it.

- A) Do you think my hypothesis *(See 'Source of the problem')* seems correct ?

  - Any other explanations you think possible ?
- B) What option would be the safest / fastest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #4

#### Protocol

So I have tried to following protocol :

1. Download old version of `apt-offline` (v.1.8.1) [Here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/apt-offline/)
2. `sudo apt remove apt-offline`
3. `sudo dpkg -i apt-offline_1.8.1_all.deb`
4. Repeat the process of updating

   1. Online PC: `apt-offline get update.sig --bundle updates.zip`
   2. Offline: `sudo apt-offline install updates.zip`
5. Install upgrades

   1. Offline: `sudo apt-offline set upgrade.sig --upgrade`
   2. Online PC: `apt-offline get upgrade.sig --bundle upgrades.zip`
   3. Offline: `sudo apt-offline install upgrades.zip`
   4. Offline: `sudo apt upgrade --no-download`

#### Result

No errors where displayed while doing the `apt-offline set --upgrade`.

One Error, non-fatal, occured during the `apt-offline get` related to the Thread. See below.

**Conclusion :** I consider the solution #4 successful, as the download of the updates was succesful.

```json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/apt-offline", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineCoreLib.py", line 2211, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineCoreLib.py", line 1360, in fetcher
    ConnectThread.stopQueue(0.2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineLib.py", line 674, in stopQueue
    if not thread.isAlive():
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 13, in <module>
    import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp, stat
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 31, in <module>
    warnings.warn("the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; "
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/apt-offline", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineCoreLib.py", line 2211, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineCoreLib.py", line 1360, in fetcher
    ConnectThread.stopQueue(0.2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineLib.py", line 674, in stopQueue
    if not thread.isAlive():
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
```